# iOS submission: invalid binary: prohibited instructions

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I’m finding this problem since yesterday when I submit an app to the app store. It validates locally ok, runs ok on my device, uploads apparently without problems, but then I get an email:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, *my_app_name*. Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90755: Invalid Binary - The following binaries in your app contains prohibited instructions:
>   /Volumes/data01/app_data/app-processing/SWAppProcessorSoftwareDigester-pv48p00ce-swpr150.cse.apple.com-17001-47015001/*more_app_details_that_give_me_no_clue*.
>   Remove the instructions from the binaries, rebuild and resubmit.

Has anyone here ever encountered this problem? 3 days ago it uploaded just fine.

Comment: Got any third party libraries? Ad trackers ?

Comment: SDL, and our own code. No ad trackers. The game needs zero permissions to run. Does not access the internet. It had all of that before and it was uploading to the store just fine and passing all validations. This only started happening yesterday.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you check out the previous version from version control and rebuild & resubmit that?

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind going back and trying again. Just before I do: the only thing that really changed between builds is that HighDPI was enabled, and the code was adapted to use it. Is that a reason to expect this kind of error?

Comment: In theory, no.  But in theory this should be working and in practice it isn't.  Debugging is the act of determining where theory and practice differ.  You cannot debug by speculation alone – verify your assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade to the latest version of Xcode and everything worked.