# Remove the prohibited instructions from the binaries - Flutter iOS app update

Tags: ios, flutter

I am facing the following error. I could validate and distribute the app successfully but getting a mail notification from the Appconnect store below error.

Any leads?

ITMS-90755: Invalid Binary - The following binaries in your app contains prohibited instructions: /Volumes/data01/app_data/awf/SWImportWorker-mr83p00ce-swpr002.cse.apple.com-300013/ff10-SoftwareImportWorker-MR_.0/CIV3UWOVLMFILKYB45HJIMJS3I/upggzhmvqveduldz/xuphayvtltagvioh/Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App. Remove the instructions from the binaries, rebuild and resubmit.

The following thread looks similar with a different error code but the solution won't work for me since I already have an updated version of XCODE
[iOS submission: invalid binary: prohibited instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169101/ios-submission-invalid-binary-prohibited-instructions)